# Who is the person referred to in the song "What One Man Can Do"?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

The song "What One Man Can Do" (by John Denver) was sung about a person.

Who is that person?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Buckminster Fuller (1895-1983)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminster_Fuller).

This assertion (without accredation) shows up in a variety of places: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Denver#Later_years_and_humanitarian_work), a [thesis](http://www.toddeklof.info/Todd_F._Eklof/Earth_files/John%20Denver%20CS.pdf) (pg 16), a [sermon](http://www.uuspokane.org/images/2013_04_28_CSofJD.pdf) (pg 7).

More authoritatively is [this anthology](https://books.google.com/books?id=VWF_6f0UCkYC&lpg=PA153&ots=w8t6SlCJkD&dq=%22what%20one%20man%20can%20do%22%20%22john%20denver%22%20buckminster%20fuller&pg=PA152#v=onepage&q=%22what%20one%20man%20can%20do%22%20%22john%20denver%22%20buckminster%20fuller&f=false) (pg 152-153) about Fuller, and [this article](http://www.people.com/people/archive/article/0,,20077012,00.html) from people magazine in 1980 on occasion of Denver performing the song for Fuller:

> ...Denver proposed "my toast to Bucky." John had composed it
>   especially for the event, and his guests, touched and teary-eyed,
>   joined in the chorus: "What one man can do is dream/What one man can
>   do is love/What one man can do is change the world and make it new
>   again." Then John Denver kissed the grand old man, stroked the back of
>   his neck and murmured, "I love you, Bucky."